# why remove function is not working in event delegation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-delegation

I want to remove `h1` tag when clicked on refresh btn but it doesn't remove h1 tag but when i run same code by using addeventlistener on each btn it run. but not run in delgation .

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var currentYear = 2018;
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  if (e.target.id === "btn") {
    var data = document.getElementById("age").value
    var output = currentYear - data;
    h1.innerText = output + "  year old";
    age.after(h1)
  }
  if (e.target.id === "dlt") {
    var data = document.getElementById("age").value = null;
    h1.remove();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1>ENTER YOUR AGE</h1>
  <input type="text" id="age">
  <button id="btn">Get Age</button>
  <button id="dlt">Refresh</button>

</div>
```

Comment: It's removing the h1 made on line 4?

Comment: Unrelated: it's useless to assign to `data` in the second `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modernized (es20xx) and somewhat streamlined version of your code. The handling is moved to a separate function. See comments within the snippet for explanation.

```js
document.querySelector(`.wrapper`).addEventListener("click", handleWrapper);

function handleWrapper(e) {
  const currentYear = 2018;
  let h1Result = e.target.closest(`.wrapper`).querySelector(`#result`);
  console.clear();
  
  // Get Age
  if (e.target.id === `btn`) {
    const createH1 = () => {
      // use insertAdjacentHTML to create H1#result
      document.querySelector(`.wrapper`).insertAdjacentHTML( `beforeend`, `
        <h1 id="result"></h1>` );
      //    ^ enable finding *this* h1, not the original  
      // return the newly create element  
      return document.querySelector(`.wrapper h1#result`);
    };
    
    let data = +document.querySelector("#age").value.trim();
    //           ^ convert to Number
    
    data = isNaN(data) || !data ? 0 : data;
    //     ^ if conversion failed, or no data, set data to 0

    // if [h1Result] is non existing create it using  
    // the createH1 function expression and set the result 
    // of the found or created element.
    // *Note: I took the liberty to call it the birth year, 
    // because that seems to be goal here.
    (h1Result || createH1()).textContent = `Birth year: ${currentYear - data}`;
  }
  
  // Refresh
  if (e.target.id === `dlt`) {
    // empty input
    document.querySelector(`#age`).value = ``;
    
    // remove the result if it exists
    if (h1Result) {
      h1Result.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>ENTER YOUR AGE</h1>
  <input type="text" id="age">
  <!-- did you mean: get birth year? -->
  <button id="btn">Get Age</button>
  <button id="dlt">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *creating* a `h1` element, you should *find* it.

So replace:

```
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
```

with

```
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
```

But then make sure to create a new `h1` whenever it is not found, and to insert it into the document in the first `if` block. It might be better to just *hide* and *show* it.

There seems also to be a mixup between birth year and age: either the user should enter their year of birth and they get the age, or vice versa.

Finally, remove the assignment to `data` in the second `if` block: it serves no purpose.

Proposed snippet:

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");

wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var currentYear = 2018;
  if (e.target.id === "btn") {
    var data = document.getElementById("age").value
    var output = currentYear - data;
    h1.innerText = output + "  year old";
    h1.classList.remove("hidden");
    age.after(h1)
  }
  if (e.target.id === "dlt") {
    h1.classList.add("hidden");
    document.getElementById("age").value = null;
    h1.remove();
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1>Enter your Year of Birth</h1>
  <input type="text" id="age">
  <button id="btn">Get Age</button>
  <button id="dlt">Refresh</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set attributes while creating elements and delete them using attributes.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var currentYear = 2018;
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.setAttribute("id", "title")
  if (e.target.id === "btn") {
    var data = document.getElementById("age").value
    var output = currentYear - data;
    h1.innerText = output + "  year old";
    age.after(h1)
  }
  if (e.target.id === "dlt") {
    var data = document.getElementById("age").value = null;
    document.getElementById("title").remove()
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1>ENTER YOUR AGE</h1>
  <input type="text" id="age">
  <button id="btn">Get Age</button>
  <button id="dlt">Refresh</button>

</div>
```

I suggest a few clean-ups. You can use display style to do your show hide.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".wrapper .btn");
const dlt = document.querySelector(".wrapper .dlt");
const input = document.querySelector(".wrapper input");
const title = document.querySelector(".wrapper .title");
title.style = "display:none";

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const currentYear = 2018;
  const output = currentYear - input.value;
  console.log(output)
  title.innerText = output + "  year old";
  title.style = "display:block"
})
dlt.addEventListener("click", () => {
  input.value = "";
  title.style = "display:none";
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1>ENTER YOUR AGE</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <h1 class="title">Get Age</h1>
  <button class="btn">Get Age</button>
  <button class="dlt">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to create you can have a permanet output h1 tag. like that.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var out = document.querySelector("#res");

wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var currentYear = 2018;
  if (e.target.id === "btn") {
    var data = document.getElementById("age").value
    var output = currentYear - data;
    out.innerText = output + "  year old";
    out.classList.remove("hidden");

    
  }
  if (e.target.id === "dlt") {
    out.classList.add("hidden");
    document.getElementById("age").value = null;
    out.innerHTML = '';
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <h1>Enter your Year of Birth</h1>
  <input type="text" id="age">
  <button id="btn">Get Age</button>
  <button id="dlt">Refresh</button>
  <h1 id="res"></h1>
</div>
```